# joining tables with concat and '%' isn't working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables I'm working with.  One is a list of article names with the title and slug and the other is a log.  The only common element in the two tables is the slug in the articles table and the path in the log table.  All the paths start with /article/(slug).  The problem is that some of the paths are /article/(slug)(another character).  I am able to join the tables with the code below.  But the second I try to use % I get no results.

This works:

```
SELECT log.path, articles.slug, articles.title, count(log.path) as num 
FROM articles LEFT JOIN log 
ON CONCAT('/article/', articles.slug) LIKE log.path 
GROUP BY log.path, articles.slug, articles.title 
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

But this gives me no results which is confusing because it should:

```
SELECT log.path, articles.slug, articles.title, count(log.path) as num 
FROM articles LEFT JOIN log 
ON CONCAT('%', articles.slug) LIKE log.path 
GROUP BY log.path, articles.slug, articles.title 
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

What I really need to work is this:

```
SELECT log.path, articles.slug, articles.title, count(log.path) as num 
FROM articles LEFT JOIN log 
ON CONCAT('%', articles.slug, '%') LIKE log.path 
GROUP BY log.path, articles.slug, articles.title 
ORDER BY num DESC;
```

What am I doing wrong?

At this point I would settle for a way to join the two tables where it gives me 3 columns: articles.slug, log.path, num.  The problem is that I don't know how to create a table where it tells me the slug for each path, because multiple paths have the same slug.  if i could do this I could group this table by slug and use SUM to add the nums together and that would solve my problem.

Comment: Try: `ON log.path LIKE CONCAT('%', articles.slug, '%')`

Comment: SQL operator `LIKE` is *not* commutative. That is: `x LIKE y` is not the same as `y LIKE x`. More specifically, "%" and "_" are wildcards only on the right-hand side.

Comment: yep.  I realized that.  I was doing more research and saw that all the examples of using % and LIKE had the % part on the right side so I tried flipping it and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQL operator `LIKE` is **not** commutative. That is: `x LIKE y` is not the same as `y LIKE x`. More specifically, "%" and "_" are wildcards only on the right-hand side.

Change your queries to

```sql
    SELECT log.path, articles.slug, articles.title, count(log.path) as num 
    FROM articles LEFT JOIN log 
    ON log.path LIKE CONCAT('/article/', articles.slug)
    GROUP BY log.path, articles.slug, articles.title 
    ORDER BY num DESC;
```

```sql
    SELECT log.path, articles.slug, articles.title, count(log.path) as num 
    FROM articles LEFT JOIN log 
    ON log.path LIKE CONCAT('%', articles.slug)
    GROUP BY log.path, articles.slug, articles.title 
    ORDER BY num DESC;
```

```
    SELECT log.path, articles.slug, articles.title, count(log.path) as num 
    FROM articles LEFT JOIN log 
    ON log.path LIKE CONCAT('%', articles.slug, '%')
    GROUP BY log.path, articles.slug, articles.title 
    ORDER BY num DESC;
```

Note that the first query only works because there is no wildcard involved. In this case, `x LIKE y` is the same as `x = y` (which **is** commutative, so in this case `y LIKE x`).